# How to make this code shorter?

Tags: php, syntax

```
if($a) {
    $b -= 1;
}
else {
    $b -= 2;
}
```

I've seen somewhere we can use the `:` here but forgot how the syntax look like and does it has any specific name that I can search for? I'm newbie, thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: There's something called Google, http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples

Comment: Short isn't always the answer. Readability/Maintainability is what's important. What's wrong with what you have there?

Comment: @Mr.Alien It's good to use Google, only if you know what to look for. He wrote that he didn't know "specific name".

Comment: @Voitcus You just need simple English, `php if else shorthand` and woaah! very first result is the link I shared

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you're looking for [Ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
$b -= $a ? 1 : 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple:

```
$b -= (($a) ? 1 : 2);
```

or

```
$b -= 2 - ((boolean) $a);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is : `$b =(($a)?($b-1):($b-2));` // b = ((if a) then (b-1) else (b-2))

Answer (score 0):

Try this

$a? $b -= 1: $b -= 2;

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is:

```
$b -= ($a) ? 1 : 2;
```